# Where was Sirius's bike all the years?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

**Please read my update below**

This is just a simple question, that came to my mind while I was listening to *the Deathly Hallows* and heard:

> Hagrid was standing ready beside the motorbike, goggles on.
>
> “Is this it? Is this Sirius’s bike?”
>
> “The very same,” said Hagrid, beaming down at Harry. “An’ the last time
>   yeh was on it, Harry, I could ﬁt yeh in one hand!”

The bike was introduced in the very first chapter of the first book:

> ‘Hagrid,’ said Dumbledore, sounding relieved. ‘At last. And where did
>   you get that motorbike?’
>
> ‘Borrowed it, Professor Dumbledore, sir,’
>   said the giant, climbing carefully off the motorbike as he spoke.
>   ‘Young Sirius Black lent it me. I’ve got him, sir.’

I assume the motorbike was not retrieved back to Sirius, since it was about the time when he was accused of killing thirteen muggles and sentenced to the Azkaban. At least I don't know anything from the books which would hint at any other conclusion.

I assume Hagrid had the motorbike. But, where was it all those years? I mean, Hagrid claims after Dumbledore's death:

> “Well, I’m stayin,” said Hagrid, fat tears still leaking out of the
>   corners of his eyes and trickling down into his tangled beard. “It’s
>   me home, it’s bin me home since I was thirteen. An’ if there’s kids
>   who wan’ me ter teach ‘em, I’ll do it. But… I dunno… Hogwarts without
>   Dumbledore…” He gulped and disappeared behind his handkerchief once
>   more, and there was silence.

So it looks like he was almost all the time there (and I think so was Sirius's bike). The motorbike might be some time at the Burrow, but I would say for only a few weeks before the transport:

> “Arthur’s done a bit o’ tinkerin’,” said Hagrid, quite oblivious to
>   Harry’s discomfort. He settled himself astride the motorcycle, which
>   creaked slightly and sank inches into the ground. “It’s got a few
>   tricks up its hindquarters now. Tha’ one was my idea.”

I do not remember the bike being mentioned anywhere else - even, when Sirius was at Grimmauld place. Harry is definitely suprised, like he never saw that motorbike before - and there is no reason not to believe him. I can't think of any other place, where the motorbike might be hidden other then Hagrid's hut.

I mean, this scene definitely adds the good nostalgia to the scene, remembering the very beginning, but I can't help myself thinking, that the motorbike disappeared after that.

**Question.** Any ideas where the motorbike might have been?

**Update 2<sup>nd</sup> June**

I did not want to accept @Anthony Grist's answer because I still thought there was something in the books. And I think, there is. Please take a time to read:

> “No, Harry, dear, I’d much rather you helped Arthur much out the
>   chickens, and Hermione, I’d be ever so grateful if you’d change the
>   sheets for Monsieur and Madame Delacour; you know they’re arriving at
>   eleven tomorrow morning.”
>
> But as it turned out, there was very little
>   to do for the chickens. “There’s no need to, er, mention it to Molly,”
>   Mr. Weasley told Harry, blocking his access to the coop, “but, er, Ted
>   Tonks sent me most of what was left of Sirius’s bike and, er, I’m
>   hiding – that’s to say, keeping – it in here. **Fantastic stuff: There’s
>   an exhaust gaskin, as I believe it’s called, the most magnificent
>   battery, and *it’ll be a great opportunity* to find out how brakes work.**
>   I’m going to try and put it all back together again when Molly’s not –
>   I mean, when I’ve got time.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, ch. 6 The Ghoul in Pajamas, pages 84-85</sub>

Seems to me, that for one thing, he is hiding it in the coop, and for second, it **really** does not sound, like he had the opportunity for the last sixteen years to play with. One might say, that it's because it is now crashed and demolished, but I think Mr. Weasley he likes to find out more about *Muggle inventions* whenever he can:

> Mr. Weasley liked Harry to sit next to him at the dinner table so that
>   he could bombard him with questions about life with Muggles, asking
>   him to explain how things like plugs and the postal service worked.
>
> “Fascinating!” he would say as Harry talked him through using a
>   telephone. “Ingenious, really, how many ways Muggles have found of
>   getting along without magic.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, ch. 4 At Flourish and Blotts, page 37</sub>

So my assumption from this is, that he could not have had the bike all the years.

Comment: IS there any special reason to assume he didn't just rent a storage locker? http://www.carlines.co.uk/tariff.html

Comment: We cannot surely cross out this possibility, since they have been established 1991.

Comment: @Richard Do they have wizarding storage lockers? Hagrid is shown to be unfamiliar with Muggle money in the first book, so seems unlikely he'd spent the past ten years or so paying a regular bill to a Muggle company to store a motorcycle.

Comment: Given how the Weasley's flying Ford car was quite happy to live in the Forbidden Forest for months, I think Hagrid could have just hidden the motorbike in the forest as well.

Comment: The Hogwarts castle is a big place, with many more or less unused rooms (think Mirror of Erised). Dumbledore was quite closely involved in the whole affair with getting Harry out of Godric’s Hollow and on to the Dursleys’, so I don’t think there’s any reason to limit Hagrid’s possible stowing places to only his own hut—I’m sure Dumbledore would have been happy to lend some storage space for the motorcycle somewhere in the castle.

Answer (score 9):

There's not a whole lot else from the books that's relevant, and this is all I can find from JKR herself on the matter:

> Rita: Whatever happend to Sirius' flying motorbike?
>
> JK Rowling replies -> Ah, good question. You'll find out, but the real sleuths among you might be able to guess.
>   
>   <sub>[World Book Day 2004 on Accio Quote!](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)</sub>

With that in mind, I think you have the answer in your question already:

> “Arthur’s done a bit o’ tinkerin’,” said Hagrid, quite oblivious to Harry’s discomfort. He settled himself astride the motorcycle, which creaked slightly and sank inches into the ground. “It’s got a few tricks up its hindquarters now. Tha’ one was my idea.”

Arthur Weasley had it. There's absolutely no room in Hagrid's hut to hide it, since it is precisely that: a hut. Arthur having it also makes sense, since he also had the Ford Anglia that he enchanted to fly, and he's absolutely fascinated with Muggle technology. It may well have been the inspiration for the enchantments on the car in the first place.

Comment: I am aware of that, but Harry visited the Burrow many times. Without any citations I think we can assume he wandered there around a lot. I guess, it is possible, that the bike was there and he simply did not care, or did not put one and one together to ask Mr. Weasley about it.

Comment: They could easily have kept it in their magical tent (or somewhere similar).

Comment: @Richard Not sure if just trying hard to be funny **or** being simply unhelpful **or** I don't understand your concept of satisfying answer. No offense.

Comment: @quapka I don't think it's entirely unreasonable to think Arthur Weasley has a garage that he works in that the rest of the family doesn't/isn't allowed to enter. Harry actually only visits The Burrow twice prior to Deathly Hallows, for *maybe* a month total - some of which was taken up by the Quidditch World Cup - and I can't imagine he would have been particularly interested in a collection of Muggle items when he'd spent most of his life separated from the wizarding world.

Comment: @quapka - They **literally** have a magical tent that's bigger on the inside and could easily be used to store a motorbike (or random furniture, etc).

Comment: @Richard: IIRC, they borrowed the tent for the World Cup - it wasn't theirs.

Comment: @Anthony Please have look at the update I have added to my question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think he only one of the two tents (the larger) was borrowed. Still, I doubt they used theirs for storing stuff while not in used, at least not something like a motorcycle. They weren't that hard-pressed for storage room, living in the countryside.

Comment: @leftaroundabout From memory, neither tent was theirs. I'd have to re-read that chapter of GoF to check though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I don't think it's properly specified, the only thing said about the girls' tent is that it's smaller and doesn't smell of cats.